# How to grab COM signal? Common principles

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serial-port, serial-communication

I have a device that's connected to a PC via COM-port in WinForms.

Do I get Signal always when device switches on?

Does device send information to COM port, or must I send a command to device for it to begin transmission of data?

What are the common principles?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the common principles?

This is extremely broad. You'd have to read the RS232 spec, or whichever serial spec the device adheres to (which could even be RS485). For the remainder of your questions, let's assume it's RS232, which is the most common by far. [Wikipedia has some good information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) once you get to the part that you actually care about; see the "Data and control signals" section. The article refers to the PC/host/Data Terminal as the DTE, and the device as the DCE.

> Do I get Signal always when device switches on?

Some devices will inform you that they are ready by holding DSR high. The host may be expected to set DTR high before the device will do anything.

From http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-19.html#ss19.2:

> Only 3 of the 9 pins have a fixed assignment: transmit, receive and
> signal ground. This is fixed by the hardware and you can't change it.
> But the other signal lines are controlled by software and may do (and
> mean) almost anything at all. However they can only be in one of two
> states: asserted (+12 volts) or negated (-12 volts). Asserted is "on"
> and negated is "off". For example, Linux software may command that DTR
> be negated and the hardware only carries out this command and puts -12
> volts on the DTR pin. A modem (or other device) that receives this DTR
> signal may do various things. If a modem has been configured a certain
> way it will hang up the telephone line when DTR is negated. In other
> cases it may ignore this signal or do something else when DTR is
> negated (turned off).

> Does device send information to COM port, or must I send a command

Depends on the device. Some devices are silent until data is requested. Some send data to the host as soon as power is applied. Devices should include documentation about what pins they use, and what expected follows should be. I've seen device documentation that provides flowcharts with regard to pins going high.